# Timestamp keyboard shortcut

Tags: bash, keyboard, shortcut-keys, mate, timestamp

On Ubuntu Mate 20.10 on a Lenovo T450 notebook, I have been trying to create a timestamp keyboard shortcut for quite a while.  The intent is to be able to insert a time stamp into any sort of file as if I typed it, whether a text file, LibreOffice Write, Calc, draw or any other type of document.
The two closest questions similar to this one are:

- [Run several xdotool commands in one line separated from each other](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515185/run-several-xdotool-commands-in-one-line-separated-from-each-other/515214#515214)
- [Timestamp hotkey won't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1334915/timestamp-hotkey-wont-work)

Following the suggestions in the first link I created the following bash script file Timestamp.sh:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 sleep 0.3s && date +%Y.%m.%d' : '%H.%M.%S
```

which when executed produces a timestamp formatted to my needs and looks like this:

```
2021.07.11 : 21.10.26
```

Now using the keyboard shortcut app in Mate `mate-keybinding-properties`, and tying the above script to F9 for testing purposes I've tried the following:

```
/home/xak/scripts/Timestamp.sh

xdotool keyup exec /home/xak/scripts/Timestamp.sh

xdotool keyup sleep 0.3s type `date +%Y.%m.%d' : '%H.%M.%S`

xdotool type "$(printf 'date\n\e ')"

bash -c 'xdotool type "`date +"%Y-%m-%d_%T`"'

bash -c 'xdotool type --clearmodifiers -delay 0 "`date +"%Y-%m-%d_%T`"'
```

None of these work.  No matter how long I hack at this (in the old positive sense of hack) or how much I search I cannot fine how to make this relatively simple thing work.

Now some of the things above that I've tried were proposed by people with a lot more experience than me but when you put them for execution as a keyboard shortcut using  `mate-keybinding-properties` they don't seem to work.  What am I missing?

To make this work would give all users the capacity to insert a timestamp into any application as needed.

Answer (score 0):

That is what I use to insert a date stamp:

```
#!/bin/sh
xdotool keyup ctrl+shift+d sleep 0.4 type $(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
```

The "keyup" statement first releases the hotkey I assigned to this script, to avoid interference of these pressed keys with the send keystrokes. A delay is still needed for me mainly for it to work in Firefox and Thunderbird. For other applications, the delay can be smaller.

This is the version I previously used (and to which I may revert to again): it uses the clipboard instead, and prevents the possibility that some keystrokes are discarded.

```
#!/bin/sh
OLDSELECT=$(xsel --clipboard --input)
CURRENTDATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
echo -n $CURRENTDATE | xsel -b -i
sleep 0.3
xdotool keyup ctrl+shift+d key Control_L+v
sleep 0.3s
echo -n $OLDSELECT | xsel  --clipboard --input
```

This saves the current (textual) keyboard and restores it in the end. In the mean time, the date is put on the clipboard and pasted into the active application using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. Again, unfortunatelly, `sleep` is required to have it work - Linux is very eager to throw away keystrokes if you type too fast. Again for Firefox and Thunderbird, a 0.3 second sleep is required for me before the clipboard is correctly restored.

Comment: Ok so maybe I'm not crazy.  When I use your first example:  
#!/bin/sh
xdotool keyup ctrl+shift+d sleep 0.4 type $(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
in Pluma or LO7 Write it does nothing, or at least it does not output anything.  If I put :
xdotool keyup sleep 0.33s type --clearmodifiers 'Test xdotools'   this works.  But I can't get it to work with $(date +...) .  I just don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Another question about your first example:  what's the ctrl+shift+d for ?
Thanks

Comment: As I said in the answer.